# IONIC Angular TypeScript -> How to use RxJs BehaviorSubject inside Service with an Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

**What I want to do?**
An application with Bluetooth data transfer where, in a Service that provide this communication to multiples components, I implement RxJs BehaviorSubject to provide Bluetooth status signaling (just enable, disable and paired, numbers) to other component (a header) that change a Bluetooth icon.
I need to share the transferred data also, but is the same issue.

**What works?**
The RxJs BehaviorSubject can pass the data to the Icon component if I use it in a Service method implementing a Set method in the source (Bluetooth Service) and a subscribe in the receiver component (header).

**The Problem:**
The Bluetooth API use an Observable to connect and provide the transfered data that works fine with a console.log, but it didn't work if I try to use a BehaviorSubject Set method to pass data to others components.

**The -> Service bluethootService.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { BluetoothSerial } from '@ionic-native/bluetooth-serial/ngx'; //https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial
  import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BluetootConnService {

  constructor(private bluetoothSerial: BluetoothSerial) {}

  //Bluetooth data Observer
  private btDataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  cuBTData= this.btDataSubject.asObservable();

  setBTData(btData: string): void {
      this.btDataSubject.next(btData);
  }

  //Bluetooth Indicator
  private btIndicatorSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
  cuBTIndicator= this.btIndicatorSubject.asObservable();

  setBTIndicator(status: number): void {
      this.btIndicatorSubject.next(status);
  }

  

  connection(address: string) {
    // Attempt to connect device with specified address, call app.deviceConnected if success
    this.bluetoothSerial.connect(address).subscribe(success => {
      this.deviceConnected();
      this.setBTIndicator(2); <------- Didn't Work ------------
      console.log("Successfully Connected");

    }, error => {
      this.setBTIndicator(1); <------- Didn't Work ------------
      console.log("Connection Error" +  error);
    });
  }

  deviceConnected() {
    // Subscribe to data receiving as soon as the delimiter is read
    this.bluetoothSerial.subscribe('\n').subscribe(serialData => {
      this.setBTData(serialData); <------- Didn't Work ------------
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }


}
```

**Where I use the Bluetooth Service:**

```
import { Component, OnInit,NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { OpenNativeSettings } from '@ionic-native/open-native-settings/ngx';
import { ShareddataService } from '../services/shareddata.service';
import { BluetootConnService } from '../services/bluetoot-conn.service'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-bluetooth',
  templateUrl: './bluetooth.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bluetooth.page.scss'],
})
export class BluetoothPage implements OnInit {

  thisPageName = "Dispositivos";

  constructor(
    public alertCtrl: AlertController,
    private openNativeSettings: OpenNativeSettings,
    private ShareddataService: ShareddataService,
    private bluetootConnService: BluetootConnService,
    public toastController: ToastController,
    private zone: NgZone
  ) { }



  devicesList = [];
  connectedId:string;



  async ItemSelected(selectedId:string) {

    console.log('Previou Connected ID:' + this.connectedId);
    if (selectedId == this.connectedId){this.Toast('Éste módulo ya está conectado'); return;}


    const connectingWait = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Conectando...',
    });
    await connectingWait.present();

    console.log('Conecting to: ' + selectedId);

    await this.bluetootConnService.connection(selectedId); <------- Here!----------

    connectingWait.dismiss();
  }

}
```

**The Header -> component pagesHeaderComponet.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { BluetootConnService } from '../../services/bluetoot-conn.service'


@Component({
  selector: 'PagesHeaderComponent',
  templateUrl: './pages-header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pages-header.component.scss'],
})
export class PagesHeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()pageName;

  ourMessage:string;
  btStatus:number; //0: Disable / 1: Enable / 2: Connected

  constructor(private ShareddataService: ShareddataService, private bluetootConnService: BluetootConnService,) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.bluetootConnService.cuBTIndicator.subscribe(data => this.btStatus = data);
  }

}
```

**Summarizing:**
How can I share data from inside an Observable to other modules?

Thank you in advance.
Best Regards!